# Mongoose find where array contains at least one object that matches with an id

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose.  I have the following model:

```
person = {
    name: String,
    projects: [
        {
            projectId: {
                type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                required:true
            },
            userNotes: {
                type: String
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

I want to be able to find all users who have at least one project with a projectId in the list `const projectIds = ['aafefaeiIE2afd', 'afeaf33afe','gg3r3a']`.  I tried doing something like this:

```
const results = Person.find({projects:{$exists:true,$contains:projectIds}});
```

But obviously this won't work because a) mongoose does not have a `$contains` and b) `person.projects` is a array of objects and not an array of strings, and I need to match on the objects `projectId`.

How do I get mongoose to perform the query I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but from what I understand this might help.

```
db.collection.find({
  "projects": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "projectId": {
        "$in": [
          "aafefaeiIE2afd" //<-- You can use your array here instead
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sAicAEZSffY)

Comment: I replaced `db.collection` with `Person`.  But this returned zero results.  Note that I am working with Mongoose in a NodeJS application, and not working directly with the mongodb database.  Is there a way for me to "inject raw queries" into mongodb from mongoose?

Comment: Would it be possible if you give a sample data to query on? Mongoose is a wrapper on `MongoDB` so all the queries should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use dot notation with [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to solve it:

```
Person.find({
  "projects.projectId": {
    $in: your_array
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PHcDXG6nZrW)